# Carbon odor, smell, etc air filter with holes

Tags: air-filter

For carbon air filters with visible holes/gaps like the above. Can it purify the odors, chemicals, etc. in the house?  (this is not about HEPA filters which I'm aware can purify pm2.5 or pm10 dusts).

Or what particular odors, smells, gas etc can carbon air filters with *visible* holes or gaps like above filter versus those without any visible holes/gap?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by `filter without any holes`?

Comment: the statements are `purify air` (make air pure), and `remove odors`

Comment: these do not filter all the air, only most of it. some air goes through the holes and misses the filter..

Comment: i mean filter without any big visible gaps in the charcoal. some carbon filters are so tightly pack you cant see through the microscopic holes

Comment: Are you sure those are actually holes _in the filter material_ and not holes in the mesh holding the filter material in place? Looks to me like an expanded metal grid clamped in a frame with some sort of filter material behind the metal mesh. Also, and most importantly, what does the manufacturer say about it? It's unlikely we can help you much here, especially since we don't know the brand/model of the thing in the picture.

Comment: [Activated carbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activated_carbon) will [adsorb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adsorption#Activated_carbon) many odorous chemicals. Note that the lifespan of the filter starts as soon as it is unwrapped and continues as long as it is exposed to air. A quick search shows lifespans of activated carbon air filters range from several months to several years. YMMV. [HEPA filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HEPA) are a different animal.

Comment: How about the air the passes thru the visible gap..how could they still be adsorbed in the not fully filled activated carbon?